# videojs doesn't show fullscreen on ios even in xcode

Tags: xcode, webview, native, wkwebview, video.js

I have a website ([donsub.com](http://donsub.com)) and it use videojs to play YouTube videos and overlay subtitles with it's plugin,

the problem is that iOS always run native player instead of videojs making the videos appear without subtitle,

I tried making an app
xcode webview can only allow inline play and avplayer can't render advance subtitles files

(I didn't try the new wkwebview yet)

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use   "playsinline": 1  also "webkit-playsinline": 1 in data-setup in video tag